# Resque jobs are scheduled correctly in development environment, but do not work in cucumber

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, resque

It was very easy to configure `resque`.
Now I have a hard time trying to pass cucumber tests with `resque_specs`.

I am quite new to rails and I cannot figure out what I should do and what I shouldn't do in my test environment.

To make `resque` work, I had to do the following in my terminal:

```
#start redis
redis-server /usr/local/etc/redis.conf
#launch resque
rake resque:work QUEUE='*'
#start resque-scheduler
rake resque:scheduler
```

`Resque` works and `resque-scheduler` is scheduling jobs appropriately.

I've added the following two lines to my features/support/env.rb

```
require 'resque_spec/scheduler'
require 'resque_spec/cucumber'
```

Here is the cucumber step.

```
Then(/^application should poll remote service every (\d+) seconds$/) do |arg1|
    RemoteServiceWorker.should have_scheduled().in(arg1)
end
```

It doesn't pass with the following error:

```
expected that RemoteServiceWorker would have [] scheduled in 30 seconds (RSpec::Expectations::ExpectationNotMetError)
```

which is not descriptive enough.
I've read `resque_specs` documentation on https://github.com/leshill/resque_spec, but it didn't help.
My guess is that `resque-scheduler` never starts up in my test environment.

The question is: Do I need to launch `redis`, `resque` and `resque-scheduler` separately in my test environment? Or the problem is in something else?

Thanks!

Comment: What version of `resque` do you use, have you tried updating it?